# Excel formula to extract text from mixed column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of mixed data which needs to be split into 2 columns in order to separate the text from the dates:

[image: BEFORE]

This is how the data should look when split:

[image]

I could do this using a VBA solution, but I was wondering if there is a sheet level formula (in col A) which would accomplish this instead.

I was able to accomplish this using various formulas over multiple(!) columns, but that process required a tremendous(!) amount of concatenation and cleanup. Maybe I am overthinking this and missing how to make a more straightforward solution (or maybe I am simply unfamiliar with how to properly reach such a solution), but I would love to learn how to approach this issue using a more elegant and straightforward process (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A1 put "Horse"

In A2 put the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(B1="",B2,A1))
```

And copy down.

Comment: I truly twisted myself into unnecessary knots using many useless and excessive approaches. Thank you so very much for breaking this down and simplifying the logic. I'm uncomfortably humbled about how I had lost my way and over-complicated the entire approach within my head :/

Comment: @5th4x4 we have all been there, that is why places like this exist.

Comment: So very true. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Formula in A1:

```
=B1
```

Formula in A2 (fill down):

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(ISNUMBER(B2),A1,B2))
```

Comment: Thank you The TTG Guy. You used the same type of approach as Scott Craner (although using ISNUMBER as opposed to ""). I truly appreciate your solution and I feel bad that I cannot accept both answers as the solution. But out of fairness, I guess its only right to accept the first solution.